# If $y_{n}=\frac{x_{1}+\ldots+x_{n}}{n}$ converges, the sequence $x_n$ must converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Given  $\left(x_{n}\right)$ a sequence, we define  $y_{n}=\frac{x_{1}+\ldots+x_{n}}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} .$ If we know $\left(y_{n}\right)$ converges. the sequence  $\left(x_{n}\right)$ must converge ?

I think yes because $y_n=\frac{1}{n}\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}
$

then by Necessary condition of series convergence $x_n \rightarrow 0$ is right?

Comment: The necessary condition is on $\sum x_n$ uniformly converging not on $1/n \sum x_n$

Answer (score 4):

No, take $x_n = (-1)^n$.  Then $x_1 + \dots + x_n$ is always equal to either $0$ or $-1$, so $y_n \to 0$, but $(x_n)$ doesn't converge.

Comment: @OP just as a remark, adding positivity does not change the conclusion take $1,3,1,3,\cdots$ then $y_n\to 2$ but $x_n$ still divergent.

Comment: @zwim beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

Remark that it does not even imply that $x_n$ is bounded.

Indeed you can take $x_i=0$ for almost all indices except for $x_{n^2}=n$ then $y_n\to \frac 12$ but $x_n$ unbounded.